# Different forms of list work differently in lapply

Tags: r, list, lapply

If I create a list like so

```
list(1:10)
```

It returns a vector of ten numbers within the first component of a single-component list

However when I create a list like so

```
list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

It creates a list with nine separate components, each containing one element.

Is there any way to specify a list with the attributes of the latter list but using the sequence specifier `:` (or `seq()`) of the former? An additional argument perhaps?

The reason I ask is that I have written a function that creates a graph from a single-integer argument. The integer specifies a component of a list of column names in a dataframe. So if the function call is `lineGraphFunct(1)` it calls the first component of a list of repeated measurements of different outcome variables (e.g. 1st component: Systolic BP time 1, Systolic BP time 2. 2nd component: Diastolic BP time 1, Diastolic BP time 2) and applies the graph function to that set of variables.

I would like to be able to use

```
lapply(list(1:10), function (x) lineGraphFunct(x))
```

to create multiple graphs but this doesn't work.

What *does* work is

```
lapply(list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), function (x) lineGraphFunct(x))
```

Is there any additional argument I can add to `list(1:10)` to make it behave like `list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`?

Comment: `as.list( 1:9 )`

Comment: `lapply(1:10, f)` and `lapply(as.list(1:10), f)` do the same thing for any `f` as far as I know, since `x[[i]]` works fine whether `x` is a `list` or a vanilla vector...

Comment: Not in this case @Frank. @G.Grothendieck's suggestion `as.list(1:9)` worked in creating the list of graphs using `lapply` and my function, whereas `list(1:9)` returns the error message `Error in DVListMorning[[x]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2` (DVList morning is my list of column names).

Comment: I did not say to use `list(1:10)` -- I'm suggesting you just use `1:10` as the first arg to `lapply`

Comment: Sorry @Frank I did not read what you wrote properly. Yes `1:9` worked as well and is even simpler. Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, the reason it is different is because `1:9` is the same as `c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)` not `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`.